# 'Note to seller' not available with PayPal button

Tags: paypal, paypal-buttons

I have a PayPal button where `cmd` = `_xclick`. I have `no_note` set to `0`, and in Sandbox there was a 'Note to seller' option. However, we've just launched and there's no note field. How can I enable it?

Bonus points if you can make it open by default :)

Answer (score 0):

That parameter works for the Classic flow of PayPal, however for the new checkout flow it is no longer supported and from my understanding the classic checkout will be removed in the future.

1. [New Checkout](http://prnt.sc/dutcaq)